# JavaScript: function returning NAN

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a codecademy.com lesson with instructions to write the calculateTotal function below. When I click run, it's returning NaN.  Anyone know what's wrong with the calculateTotal function as I wrote it that's making it return NaN. Note, I understand that NaN means not a number...

```
// runner times
var carlos = [9.6,10.6,11.2,10.3,11.5];
var liu = [10.6,11.2,9.4,12.3,10.1];
var timothy = [12.2,11.8,12.5,10.9,11.1];

// declare your function calculateTotal here
var calculateTotal = function(raceTimes){
    var totalTime; 
    for(i = 0; i < raceTimes.length; i++){
        totalTime += raceTimes[i]; 
        return totalTime; 
    }
};

var liuTotal = calculateTotal(liu);

console.log(liuTotal);
```

Note, many of the people answering this question have said that var totalTime has to be set to "O". However, in the next codecademy lessson, the author writes a function with totalTime not set to anything and it works

```
var calculateAverage = function (raceTimes) {
  var totalTime;
  for ( i = 0; i < raceTimes.length; i++ ) {
    totalTime = (totalTime || 0) + raceTimes[i];
  }
// assign variable averageTime
var averageTime = totalTime / raceTimes.length; 

  return averageTime;
};
```

Comment: Well at least it's not a function returning [`NyaN`](http://nyan.cat)

Comment: a) You're not setting totaltime to zero (or another value) to initialise it. b) You're returning after only one iteration

Comment: You don't have to set totalTime to zero. But set it to any number you want, so then you can add a number to a number and get a number. Otherwise it is not a number.

Comment: @IvanKuckir That's what I said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `totalTime` is not defined -- adding something to an undefined results in `NaN`
2. You are returning INSIDE your loop.

Fix:

```
var totalTime=0;
for(i = 0; i < raceTimes.length; i++){
    totalTime += raceTimes[i]; 
}
return totalTime;
```

Comment: that's great, but in the next lesson, the codecademy tutors write a function with var totalTime the way that I did, and it works. Why does this function work? var calculateAverage = function (raceTimes) {
  var totalTime;
  for ( i = 0; i < raceTimes.length; i++ ) {
    totalTime = (totalTime || 0) + raceTimes[i];
  }
// assign variable averageTime
var averageTime = totalTime / raceTimes.length; 
    
  return averageTime;
};

Comment: `(totalTime || 0)` tests `totalTime` on each iteration to see if it's defined or not. If not, it uses zero instead. The first time through the loop, this would result in 0 instead of undefined, so the addition would work. The `||` operator is a switch - it returns the first operand if it's not *falsy* or the 2nd operand if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your `totalTime` doesn't have an initial value, so it starts off as `undefined`. You can't add a number to `undefined` and get a number:

```
var totalTime; // implicitly initialized to undefined 
for(i = 0; i < raceTimes.length; i++){
    totalTime += raceTimes[i];  // undefined + raceTimes[i] = NaN
    return totalTime; 
}
```

Initialize it to `0`.

```
var totalTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized `totalTime` with a value. So it defaults to `undefined`. Therefore on each iteration, undefined is being added, yielding `NaN`.