# Same calculation returns NaN from inside object BUT returns integer from a function doing the same calculation

Tags: javascript, types

For the life of me, I cannot figure why the same calculation return two different data type between:

1. Calculating from inside the object definition AND
2. Outside in hand-made function

I have already looked at:
   [JavaScript calculation returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522179/javascript-calculation-returns-nan)
 & [JavaScript: function returning NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149945/javascript-function-returning-nan?r=SearchResults&s=3|99.8302)

and I am still baffled. Please HELP.

Here is my code and it's run:

```
var question_answer = {
  question1: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  question2: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  answer_inside: parseInt(this.question1 + this.question2),
};

console.log(typeof(question_answer.answer_inside))
console.log(question_answer.answer_inside)

console.log(typeof(check_answer()));
console.log(check_answer());


function check_answer() {
          real_ans = question_answer.question1 + question_answer.question2;
          return real_ans;
          }


prompt::node ./test.js
number
NaN
number
9
```

Comment: The code in the object that refers to `this` is wrong. The value of `this` is not changed inside the body of an object initializer.

Comment: If you move your `answer_inside` out of the object literal, it should work, ie `question_answer.answer_inside = parseInt(question_answer.question1 + question_answer.question2)`

Comment: by the way, you wouldn't need to parseInt when adding two Math.floor values

Comment: Thank you all! @Phil's idea worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use getter, this won't be refer to the object. 
And this.question1 and this.question2 are undefined, that's why your answer_inside get NaN.

```js
var question_answer = {
  question1: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  question2: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  get answer_inside(){ return this.question1 + this.question2}
};

console.log(typeof(question_answer.answer_inside))
console.log(question_answer.answer_inside)

console.log(typeof(check_answer()));
console.log(check_answer());


function check_answer() {
          real_ans = question_answer.question1 + question_answer.question2;
          return real_ans;
          }
```